# How to determine if a carbon instance is equal to 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, laravel

My users have a date field which is set to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 by default. I want to be able to determine if a user has their field set to this date.

However, when I die and dump the field I get something like this:

> Carbon {#290 ▼   +"date": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00.000000"
>
> +"timezone_type": A number
>
> +"timezone": My timezone }

I have tried the following

```
if ($user->date == null)

if ($user->date == 00:00:00.000000)

if (!$user->date)
```

I'm a bit of a loss as to how I will determine that the date is zero

Comment: `"However, when I die"` Are you sure this is not a typo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$user->date` is a carbon instance. so you can check if date is zero like

```
if($user->date->year < 1) { //zero date logic }
```

for more you can check carbon documentation : http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score -2):

please try this one

```
if ($user->date == ''){//perform your logic here}
```